# How to get character that comes after a particular substring, in python

Tags: python, string, split

Imagine I have the text: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?page=2#section0`

If my string contains `?page=`, I want to be able to get `2` from the string (and *not* `2#section0`, just the number after `?page=`).

For instance, if I have `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?page=32#section0`, I ought to be able to get `32`.

What's the fastest way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be with a regular expression: `(\d)` means "digit", `(\d+)` means "1 or more digit" and `page=(\d+)` means "1 or more digit following the text `page=`. In Python,

```
import re
re.search('page=(\d+)', yourstring).group(1)
```